# why assign a different function for descriptor.value when use typescript decorator

Tags: javascript, typescript, decorator, typescript-decorator

I'm new to Typescript and really get confused with the use of decorator. I saw some code as below:

```
function log(target: any, key: string, descriptor: any) {
    const original = descriptor.value;
    descriptor.value = function (...args: any[]) {
        // Call the original method
        const result = original.apply(this, args);
        // Log the call, and the result
        console.log(`${key} with args ${JSON.stringify(args)} returned ${JSON.stringify(result)}`);
        // Return the result
        return result;
    }
    return descriptor;
}

class Calculator {
    // Using the decorator
    @log
    square(num: number) {
        return num * num;
    }
}

const calculator = new Calculator();
// square with args [2] returned 4
calculator.square(2);
```

below is my questions:

Q1- I understand that `descriptor.value` contains the original `square` method, then  another anonymous function is assigned to `descriptor.value`, then return `descriptor`, I am not sure what exact it mean, but I guess the new function that `descriptor.value` contains will get called, but by whom? who will call the decorator log function and get the returned `descriptor` and call its value function?/Who is going to call `log` function?

Q2- why the new assigned anonymous function takes a array of parameter, isn't that a single parameter is enough as below:

```
...
descriptor.value = function (args: any) {
   ...
}
```

Q3- If I don't assign a different function to `descriptor.value` as:

```
function log(target: any, key: string, descriptor: any) {
    const original = descriptor.value; //does nothing
    return descriptor;
}
```

I assume the `square` method will be called twice, but it just get called once. So how come when you assign `descriptor.value` to a new different function then the new function will get called, which is inconsistent?